# STDERR output from Hadoop, this does mean some issue?

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop, mrjob

I'm using Mrjob-Hadoop with Python2.7, Ubuntu 14.04 and I had the following screen output:

```
no configs found; falling back on auto-configuration
no configs found; falling back on auto-configuration
creating tmp directory /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886
writing wrapper script to /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/setup-wrapper.sh

PLEASE NOTE: Starting in mrjob v0.5.0, protocols will be strict by default. It's recommended you run your job with --strict-protocols or set up mrjob.conf as described at https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/whats-new.html#ready-for-strict-protocols

writing to /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/step-0-mapper_part-00000
> sh -ex setup-wrapper.sh /usr/bin/python word-document.py --step-num=0 --mapper /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/input_part-00000 > /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/step-0-mapper_part-00000
writing to /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/step-0-mapper_part-00001
> sh -ex setup-wrapper.sh /usr/bin/python word-document.py --step-num=0 --mapper /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/input_part-00001 > /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/step-0-mapper_part-00001
STDERR: + __mrjob_PWD=/tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/job_local_dir/0/mapper/0
STDERR: + exec
STDERR: + /usr/bin/python -c import fcntl; fcntl.flock(9, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
STDERR: + export PYTHONPATH=/tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/job_local_dir/0/mapper/0/mrjob.tar.gz:/home/ignacio/shogun-install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/ignacio/shogun/examples/undocumented/python_modular:
STDERR: + exec
STDERR: + cd /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/job_local_dir/0/mapper/0
STDERR: + /usr/bin/python word-document.py --step-num=0 --mapper /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/input_part-00000
STDERR: + __mrjob_PWD=/tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/job_local_dir/0/mapper/1
STDERR: + exec
STDERR: + /usr/bin/python -c import fcntl; fcntl.flock(9, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
STDERR: + export PYTHONPATH=/tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/job_local_dir/0/mapper/1/mrjob.tar.gz:/home/ignacio/shogun-install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/ignacio/shogun/examples/undocumented/python_modular:
STDERR: + exec
STDERR: + cd /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/job_local_dir/0/mapper/1
STDERR: + /usr/bin/python word-document.py --step-num=0 --mapper /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/input_part-00001
Counters from step 1:
  (no counters found)
writing to /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/step-0-mapper-sorted
> sort /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/step-0-mapper_part-00000 /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/step-0-mapper_part-00001
writing to /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/step-0-reducer_part-00000
> sh -ex setup-wrapper.sh /usr/bin/python word-document.py --step-num=0 --reducer /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/input_part-00000 > /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/step-0-reducer_part-00000
writing to /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/step-0-reducer_part-00001
> sh -ex setup-wrapper.sh /usr/bin/python word-document.py --step-num=0 --reducer /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/input_part-00001 > /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/step-0-reducer_part-00001
STDERR: + __mrjob_PWD=/tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/job_local_dir/0/reducer/0
STDERR: + exec
STDERR: + /usr/bin/python -c import fcntl; fcntl.flock(9, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
STDERR: + export PYTHONPATH=/tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/job_local_dir/0/reducer/0/mrjob.tar.gz:/home/ignacio/shogun-install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/ignacio/shogun/examples/undocumented/python_modular:
STDERR: + exec
STDERR: + cd /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/job_local_dir/0/reducer/0
STDERR: + /usr/bin/python word-document.py --step-num=0 --reducer /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/input_part-00000
STDERR: + __mrjob_PWD=/tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/job_local_dir/0/reducer/1
STDERR: + exec
STDERR: + /usr/bin/python -c import fcntl; fcntl.flock(9, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
STDERR: + export PYTHONPATH=/tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/job_local_dir/0/reducer/1/mrjob.tar.gz:/home/ignacio/shogun-install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/ignacio/shogun/examples/undocumented/python_modular:
STDERR: + exec
STDERR: + cd /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/job_local_dir/0/reducer/1
STDERR: + /usr/bin/python word-document.py --step-num=0 --reducer /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/input_part-00001
Counters from step 1:
  (no counters found)
Moving /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/step-0-reducer_part-00000 -> /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/output/part-00000
Moving /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/step-0-reducer_part-00001 -> /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/output/part-00001
Streaming final output from /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886/output
removing tmp directory /tmp/word-document.hduser.20160122.065849.953886
```

Could you say if there is some problem? I mean, the jobs finished but the `STDERR:` keywords are noisy to me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your job isn't generating any output. Could you please post word-document.py and your input data?